# I am tyring to delete any record it is deleting first record using laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i am trying to delete specific record from db but unfortunately first record is deleting from db please help me how can i delete specific record ? thank u.

**controller**

```
     public function destroy(Request $request)
      {   

        $room = Room::where('id',$request->room_id)->first();

        if ($room != null) {
            $room->delete();
            RoomDetail::where('room_id',$room->id)->delete();
        }

       return redirect()->route('room');
}
```

**html view**

```
                         @foreach ($rooms as  $value)                           
                                  <form  name="myForm" action="{{route('room.destroy')}}" 
                                         method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        <input type="text" value="{{$value->id}}" 
                                        name="room_id" >
                                    <button  type="submit" class="btn bg-primary-light px-3 me- 
                                   2 py-2 " onclick="roomFunction()" ><i class='bx bx-trash'></i> 
                                   </button>
                            </form>
                          @endforeach
```

**javascript**

```
function roomFunction() {
event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
var form = document.forms["myForm"];
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#4fa7f3",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    form.submit();
  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "", "error");
  }
});
}
```

Comment: please add your controller function code

Comment: You kept the form inside foreach loop. its always getting first value. put the foreach inside form

Comment: Can you add your database table Structure & Model of Room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small change is needed.

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
      {   

        $room = Room::where('id', $request->room_id)->first();

        if ($room != null) {
            RoomDetail::where('room_id', $room->id)->delete();
            Room::where('id', $request->room_id)->delete();
        }

       return redirect()->route('room');
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {          
     $('#roomID').on('change', function () {
        var roomID = this.value;

   $('#destroy').on('click', function () {
   swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#4fa7f3",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
});
                 $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('room.destroy')}}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        room_id: roomID,
                        _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',                 
                    success: function (successful) {
                    console.log("Success!");
                  } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "", "error");
                }
    });
   });
  });
});
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($rooms as  $value)                           
<form name="myForm" action="{{route('room.destroy')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
<input id="roomID" type="text" value="{{$value->id}}" name="room_id" >
  <button id="destroy" type="submit" class="btn bg-primary-light px-3 me- 
                                   2 py-2"><i class='bx bx-trash'></i> 
                                   </button>
    </form>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: when i remove this (onclick="roomFunction()")  from button  it will work perfectly but i want to also use this because this is confirmation delete window .

Comment: please send your JS

Comment: please check i have updated